# Eclipse debug not working for Spring based testng AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests

Tags: eclipse, testng, spring-test, testng-eclipse

I am facing a strange issue. My eclipse debug ( Not stopping at breakpoint ) is not working when my testng test case extend AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests. It runs absolute fine when I run the same code without extending AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests .
Plain testng case

```
package in.xxx.core.integration;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestXXX {

    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        System.out.println("verifyFooName: Is foo not null? ");
    }
}
```

Code with Spring based testng testcase
    package in.xxx.core.integration;

```
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:test-spring-application-context.xml" })

public class TestXXX extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Test
    public void testMe() {
       System.out.println("verifyFooName: Is foo not null? ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you set your break point? In the test class, or somewhere else?

Comment: FWIW, I just set a break point within the test method of a class that extends `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`, and I don't have any problems stepping through it with the Eclipse debugger using `Debug As... TestNG Test`.